# Hyper-V: The image's hash and certificate are not allowed

Tags: windows, hyper-v

When trying to install Fedora 39 on a Hyper-V server I am faced with the error "The image's hash and certificate are not allowed" directly at startup. [image]

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to solve the issue:

1. Go to Settings -> Security -> Disable Secure Boot
2. Go to Settings -> Security -> instead of "Microsoft Windows" select template "Microsoft UEFI Certificate Authority"

I personally prefer the latter because it allows to keep Secure Boot enabled.

Screenshot (in German, but should be clear)
[image]